# Kubuntu 18.04 LTS splash screen is black

Tags: boot, grub2, kubuntu, plymouth

When booting or rebooting, the splash screen of Kubuntu is black/blank.  I do not see grub prompts nor the splash.  Here is what I have attempted so far:

I figured the answer was in /etc/default/grub, but when I insert nomodeset to quiet splash, all that happens is it slightly reduces the resolution of my screen at all times during use.  Still no splash.

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"

Tried regular splash:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash"

Still a black or blank splash.  But when I use an empty default and then run "update-grub", I get the old-time scrolling commands.

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""

How can I get a working splash screen?  I also checked the /etc/alternatives/default.plymouth file, but it appears correct.

This is a fresh install.  Running all updates in Muon did not change any results.  Once I get to the user selection login screen everything works fine.  I have an older AMD video card using the open source driver.

Comment: I can't help with your issue, but on two old systems I use where the video cards (ATI/AMD on both from memory) have two screen connectors, but I'm only using one of them - the `plymouth` screen only displays on one connector. If the other card's DVI-connector is used no `plymouth` will be displayed.   This may not help you, but it's what I found on one old dell, and one hp box (using 14.04 LTS & 16.04 LTS).